# Server two data streams. How to seperate two incoming data types

Tags: python, server

I have a server on which I mainly want to work with incoming audio data received as bytes.
Yet in order to take any kind of client command I want uft-8 data to be sent aswell.
How do I identify two different data types and use them on the server?
As of now I always get: UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xff in position 4: invalid start byte

as soon as the byte data hits the server.

Comment: how do you read data? do you use `socket` or web server? If you use `socket` then maybe add some extra information before any data - one byte which will define what type of data you send. You may also need to add few bytes with size of data because socket may send it splited to smaller parts or it may join few message in one data. And if you use web server then you could send data as `JSON` - ie. `{"type": "audio", "data": ... }`

Comment: I'm using socket. I will try that approach. Thank you.